# For in loop on object, and .find, returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through an object (`objectToLoop`) and check to see if if contains the key `comments_text`. If it does, I want to check `comments_text`, and if the `key` within `comments_text` matches `commentId`, I want to set `let item` to the entire object within `coments_text`.

I'm trying to set `let item` to the following, but I'm getting "undefined":

```
{
 commenter_comment: "reedwe",
 commenter_handle: "FALCON1",
 commenter_uid: "ZALb0B3wZEWjfdFIUOxteJRl9Xu1",
 key: "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"
}
```

Advice and feedback appreciated.

```js
const commentId = "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"

const objectToLoop = {
  comment: false,
  comments_text: {
    commenter_comment: "reedwe",
    commenter_handle: "FALCON1",
    commenter_uid: "ZALb0B3wZEWjfdFIUOxteJRl9Xu1",
    key: "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"
  },
  handle: "TURTLE1",
  key: "-MkeOOUboKdOcC3Sannl",
  title: "hello2"
}

function returnMatchingComment(commentIdKey) {
  let item;
  for (const post in objectToLoop) {
    if (post.comments_text) {
      item = Object.values(post.comments_text).find(
        (comment) => comment.key === commentIdKey
      )
    };
    if (item) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return item
}
console.log(
  returnMatchingComment(commentId)
)
```

Comment: _"and if the `key` within `comments_text` matches `commentId`"_ - Then why `Object.values(post.comments_text)`?

Comment: `for..in` loops over object keys. Not the values. Keys are strings. Strings don't have a `comments_text` property.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `objectToLoop` is meant to be an object?

Comment: Since `objectToLoop` is an object, you don't need a loop and can instead use: `let item = objectToLoop.comments_text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use the `for...in` loop. You can first check if `objectToLoop` has the property `comments_text` by using [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and check if `objectToLoop?.comments_text?.key == commentId`. I used `?.` (optional chaining) so that if `objectToLoop.comments_text` didn't exist, it would just return `undefined` and not throw an ugly error. 
Example:

```js
const commentId = "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"

const objectToLoop = {
  comment: false,
  comments_text: {
    commenter_comment: "reedwe",
    commenter_handle: "FALCON1",
    commenter_uid: "ZALb0B3wZEWjfdFIUOxteJRl9Xu1",
    key: "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"
  },
  handle: "TURTLE1",
  key: "-MkeOOUboKdOcC3Sannl",
  title: "hello2"
}
if(objectToLoop.hasOwnProperty('comments_text') && objectToLoop?.comments_text?.key == commentId) { 
    let item = objectToLoop.comments_text;
    console.log(item)
}
```

To be honest, we don't even need `objectToLoop.hasOwnProperty('comments_text')` as with optional chaining (as mentioned earlier on), `objectToLoop?.comments_text?.key == commentId` would just return `undefined` if `objectToLoop.comments_text` did not exist or `false` if `objectToLoop.comments_text.key` was not equal to `commentId`. 
Example 2:

```js
const commentId = "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"

const objectToLoop = {
  comment: false,
  comments_text: {
    commenter_comment: "reedwe",
    commenter_handle: "FALCON1",
    commenter_uid: "ZALb0B3wZEWjfdFIUOxteJRl9Xu1",
    key: "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"
  },
  handle: "TURTLE1",
  key: "-MkeOOUboKdOcC3Sannl",
  title: "hello2"
}

if(objectToLoop?.comments_text?.key == commentId) { 
    let item = objectToLoop.comments_text;
    console.log(item)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put some debug.Your if never fire.
The 'i' log gives you a big information =)

```js
const commentId = "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"

const objectToLoop = {
  comment: false,
  comments_text: {
    commenter_comment: "reedwe",
    commenter_handle: "FALCON1",
    commenter_uid: "ZALb0B3wZEWjfdFIUOxteJRl9Xu1",
    key: "-MlaKXBMXzXIBJMsZQNX"
  },
  handle: "TURTLE1",
  key: "-MkeOOUboKdOcC3Sannl",
  title: "hello2"
}

function returnMatchingComment(commentIdKey) {
  let item;
  var i =0;
  for (const post in objectToLoop) {
    console.log(post,i++);
    if (post.comments_text) {
      console.log("APPEND");
      item = Object.values(post.comments_text).find(
        (comment) => comment.key === commentIdKey
      )
    };
    if (item) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return item
}
console.log(
  returnMatchingComment(commentId)
)
```

Comment: doesn't answer question in OP